# Join and Unflatten Collection - EF Two TVF Models

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, odata

I'm publishing an OData service. I have two models that need to be exposed to the OData endpoint. I've abstracted my model to easy to visualize Blog/Posts model below. This service works well when both are stored in Views in the DB. In that case, when someone uses $expand to include the Posts property, the tables are joined and unflattened automatically. I use EF's Include method to eagerly load the Posts.

Now my DBA wants to use [Table Valued Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx) to access these two sets in order to apply permission screening based on the querying user. The interface would be something like this:

```
IQueryable<Blog> Blogs(int userId);
IQueryable<Post> Posts(int userId);
```

I can access these individually and even join one View to a TVF but the problem is that I can no longer use EF's [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj574232.aspx) method to eagerly populate the Posts collection when they are both backed by TVFs.

**Problem: I need to be able to query (JOIN) the two sets and reassemble (unflatten) the result set into Blogs that contain a collection of Posts. The solution also needs to avoid the [N+1 Selects Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue).**

I realize the use of Functions is uncommon with EF but has anyone come across this issue? Is there a way to do this using Linq to Entities, Automapper, Store Functions, or any other way?

I am using Web API with EF Code First, Automapper's [Queryable Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions), and the [Store Functions](https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/) library to enable TVFs in EF queries.

```
public class Blog 
{
  public Blog()
  {
    Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
  }
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int BlogId { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }

  public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```